# How to use mod_rewrite with Glassfish 4

Tags: http, mod-rewrite, glassfish, cpanel, cname

I have a java ee web app deployed on a glassfish application server running on a windows server. So the url looks something like this https://myvm:8181/my-app. I have a domain name `www.myapp.com` that has a cname pointing to my windows vm. I have two questions:

1. How do use a mod_rewrite with glassfish to remove the port number from my vm url?
2. How do i make sure that when the user enters my domain name without https that it automatically goes to my https url?

Please help.